# CORS Policy Error with Third Party Javascript Library

Tags: lightning-web-components, google-map, content-security-policy

I'm trying to build my own Google Maps LWC.   I understand and am aware that there is a native Lightning Map component, but I am wishing to build my own, and utilizing my own billing independent of Salesforce for it.

I've gone ahead and uploaded the Google Maps JS library as a static resource, and I've referenced inside my component, [following the guidelines listed here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/js_third_party_library).   Unfortunately, When I load the screen, I see `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/42/1/common.js' from origin 'https://myscratchorg-dev-ed.lightning.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` in the JS console and the component does not render.

I've confirmed that maps.googleapis.com is added to Setup > CORS, Setup > Remote Site, and Setup > CSP Trusted Sites.   None of these exclusions appear to remediating the error.

Has anyone else done something similar?  I ran into a very similar situation when trying to use Azure Maps as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on the requested resource](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249068/blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-on-the-requested)

Comment: Not really.  The solution provided was to use an alternative charting library to what Google is offering.